# Can Content Negotiation Be Used to Control Return Types in the ASP.NET WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

We're building a web api whose GET methods return DTOs. We'd like to build it so that, under certain circumstances, these DTOs are stripped of unnecessary properties in an effort to control the volume of data being sent down to the client. For example, when we return one of our email DTOs we sometimes would like the client to specify that it only needs a subject, date and ID and not the body of the email. In other scenarios, of course, the body of the email is needed.

What's the best way in the MVC WebApi to do this? I've looked into MediaTypeFormatters but they seem focused on the format of the data (JSONP, XML) rather than the content.

Comment: there is a number of ways to do this, preferably via message handlers, but it's hard to say anything since you haven't specified how would determine what kind of object/property set will be returned in response to a given request.

via a custom header? via some IP whitelist? via querystring?

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. I'd like to use a custom header to indicate the object/property set to be returned. I'll look into message handlers more. Thanks.

Comment: Facebook Graph API uses a querystring parameter _fields_ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/selecting-results/ , although that's not very RESTy

Comment: I think you might find your answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606675/asp-net-web-api-partial-response-json-serialization

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you would like to have a custom mediatype.

This could be used in combination with a custom MediaTypeFormatter.

For instance, you could define your own mediatype (this is a *bad* example of a name):

```
application/vnd.me-shortform
```

And then, in your code you can omit filling in the emailbody and let the default formatter format your result.

Or you could write your own MediaTypeFormatter (subclassing an existing one) and register it for your custom mediatype.

Then, in the MediaTypeFormatter you could either through attributes on your DTO or something similar decide that the email body is not necessary and omit having it as part of the result.

[Mark Seeman on Vendor Media Types](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/04/24/VendorMediaTypesWithTheASPNETWebAPI.aspx) should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Could you explain why your mediatype name is a bad example?