# Asp.NET WebApi Convention based approach Url/Route query

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm not sure of the 'best practice' way forward for an asp.net webapi convention based rest service that needs to return a 'sub property' of a resource.

eg:

```
UsersController

public User Get(int id) { ... } //returns named user via /api/v1/Users/23
```

but if I want to return a given users role collection I think I'd like a url of `/api/v1/Users/23/Roles`

If you were using my api would you consider this acceptable?

If it is acceptable, what would my routeTemplate and method signature look like (sorry if this is obvious - I've really confused myself today)

All the web api examples I can find are too simple and just use DELETE,PUT,POST and two GET's - none seem to cover anything like sub properties (as above) or Partial Responses
`/api/v1/Users/23?fields=id,name` - If anybody knows of a good example out there that would be awesome.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Roles**

Roles looks like a very sensible sub resource.

Assuming you will want to list and remove roles from the user using http verbs... then you can use two controllers, one for Users and another for Roles. Your routes would then look like so:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "UserApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/Users/{userId}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Your roles controller would then have methods like:

```cs
public class RolesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/v1/users/1/roles
    public IEnumerable<Role> Get(int userId)
    {
        //
    }

    // GET api/v1/users/1/roles/1
    public IEnumerable<Role> Get(int userId, int id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

**Roles as a partial response of User**

*For what formats and standard to use for the request:*

apigee do a free eBook on their site where they make design recommendation's and observations about existing API's.

They describe partial response examples from LinkedIn, Facebook and Google. It is covered in one of their blogs [here](http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_can_your_api_give_developers_just_the_information) and in their book [here](http://blog.apigee.com/detail/announcement_new_ebook_on_web_api_design).

*How with WebApi ASP.NET*

Assuming the use of JSON as the content type, then a similar question has been asked before [ASP.NET Web API partial response Json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606675/asp-net-web-api-partial-response-json-serialization), in short you will need to pass the query param for "?Fields=" or such like into a custom `ContractResolver`.

Comment: Fantastic. I think you have just helped me have a route matching breakthrough :)