# designing two webapi methods with same base url

Tags: asp.net-web-api, crud, apiblueprint

In my WebAPI being desinged, I have urls such as

```
https://<base_url>api/projects/{projectId}/samples/ (POST)
```

and I need to specify another method with POST and same base URL, that does things similarly to original, but accepts different payload and returns different payload. At the moment I have

```
https://<base_url>api/projects/{projectId}/samples/savemasscreation
```

"modification" but I am not sure it is a good API practice. What would be the best way to design a modifier for method without necessity to change the resource URL? What would be the best practice - use another HTTP verb, add ?optionalparameter to URL, or something else?

Comment: Can you describe the who POST actions in more detail. Are they interacting with the same object in different ways or totally different objects?

Comment: @SteveFenton more like different objects, but the logical action is the same

Comment: I would expect the URL to reflect that... i.e. `https://<base_url>api/customers/` and `https://<base_url>api/orders/` (both being a POST for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET you can specify the route with a `[Route()]` attribute and those methods must accept different number of parameters in order to work since both are POST. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773720/asp-net-webapi-convention-based-approach-url-route-query).